# React native firebase OAuth authorization

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, dns

I am getting this error and trying to get solution but unable to resolve this issue. I have configure firebase thing and i am using react native for firebase email and password authentication. And got that error

I check that need to setup OAuth in firebase console project,

Google cloud setting, after that need to add domain, so that i enter login password and it will authorization